# Найти рекурсию двух функций, зависящих одна от другой

Tags: c++, рекурсия

```
Ak=0.3Ak+0.2Bk
Bk=Ak+Bk
```

В делфи есть *forward*, что можно сделать в *с++*?

Comment: И где тут база рекурсии??? Ваша формула беконечно рекурсивна. Никакой "forward в делфи" не поможет вам высчислить бессмысленную рекурсию.

Comment: @AnT: Bk=Ak+Bk => Ak == 0, Ak=0.3Ak+0.2Bk превращается в 0 = 0 + 0.2Bk => Bk == 0.

Comment: тогда наверное clang компилятор был прав, сгенерировав просто "return 0;" для обоих функций?

Answer (score 2):

В C++ тоже есть

```
double FooBar();

double FooBar()
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Можно, если несложно, какой-нибудь небольшой пример описи таких функций?

Comment: @Yuralug: ищите на третьей планете^W^W^W по ключевым словам _forward declaration_.

Comment: Решил задачу, да - сваливается, хотя алгоритм правильный.

Comment: @Yuralug: Вряд ли правильный. Может, вы имели в виду `A[k+1]=0.3A[k]+0.2B[k]; B[k+1]=A[k]+B[k];`? И ещё для рекуррентного соотношения нужны начальные значения.

Comment: Начальные значения есть, я уже подставил, плюс есть функция факториала для k. Ошибка одна  - error writing output file.

Answer (score 2):

Где то так

```
float B(int k);
float A(int k) {
  return 0.3 * A(k) + 0.2*B(k);
}

float B(int k) {
  return A(k) + B(k);
}
```

вот только не пытайтесь это запускать - зависнет. Как минимум, следующий элемент должен зависеть от предыдущего, а не от себя самого. А во вторых, должно быть так называемое "условие выхода из рекурсии".

Comment: Почему зависнет? Очень быстро свалится с stack overflow.

Comment: ну, не очень быстро, но немного поработает:)
Я посмотрел, что генерирует clang 3.5 и старше, если указать `-Os`, там может и зависнуть:) Хотя какая разница.